# Automating addition of sites to Exception sites in java control panel

Tags: java, java-web-start

I am creating a Java webstart application which will be downloaded as JNLP and will run at the local machine. Purpose is to read some info about local files.

But the issue is I am getting a warning message for security. After adding the site address to Java control panel, the warning message went off.

I have automated this by altering the `exception.sites` file located in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security` in Windows OS.

Where this file (`exception.sites`) exists in LINUX and MAC machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The location of the exception site list is set in the deployment.user.security.exception.sites property. The default location is {deployment.user.home}/security/exception.sites.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/exception_site_list.html

Also good to know: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/properties.html